# Error: Cannot find module 'eslint/lib/rules/no-unused-expressions'

Tags: reactjs, npm, node-modules, eslint

After installing ESLint through NPM, I'm getting the following error in my browser:

> Error: Cannot find module 'eslint/lib/rules/no-unused-expressions'
>   Referenced from:

Any idea what could cause this and how I can fix it?

Comment: do you init eslint ?
eslint --init

Comment: do you run eslint?, eslint yourfile.js

Comment: do you have eslintrc file ??

Comment: eslint --init produce --> 'eslint' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: npm i eslint -g

Answer (score 13):

**Try these steps:**

1. Delete package-lock.json file
2. Delete node_modules folder
3. Delete .eslintrc file
4. Remove devDependencies that contains 'eslint'
5. In the terminal type: npm install
6. In the terminal type: npm run start

In case you want to have eslint, try checking if you have in your devDependencies the line below:

```
"eslint": "5.6.0"
```

1. NPM INSTALL ESLINT

Comment: After following above it produces an another error and now the npm start is also not working .

Comment: You need to make sure when you removed the eslint from your package.json you didn't break the json. Can you post your package.json file?

Comment: In addition, I asked you to deleted the package-lock.json and not the package.json.

Comment: so your way of fixing eslint is removing eslint?

Comment: @GeorgeMarin no, it is removing eslint completely and if desired to have eslint, add that eslint again + npm install eslint

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue while using a create-react-app. React scripts already come with an eslint version installed and that means you shouldn't need to install eslint on your own. I fixed this issue by doing the following:

1. Deleted node-modules folder
2. Deleted my package-lock.json file
3. Removed my local installation of eslint from the package.json file
4. Installed all packages again `npm install`
5. `npm start` and everything was working fine again

Answer (score 1):

Deleted node-modules folder
Deleted my package-lock.json file
Removed eslint from the package.json file
Installed all packages again

```
npm install   
npm start
```

and everything was working fine again

Answer (score 1):

**Easy fix #1**

```
npm i -D --save eslint-loader
```

**Easy fix #2**

```
npm i -D --save eslint@5.16.0
```

**Explanation**:

- If you look at the error stack trace you'll see the error is actually fired from `eslint-loader/index.js` (so not `eslint`).
- Then in node_modules, you can find `eslint-loader` and check the version in its `package.json`. It's probably quite outdated. Mine was at 1.9.0, while the current version of `eslint-loader` is 4.0.2
- And back to the error - that path that it is complaining about apparently did get changed from `eslint/lib/formatters/stylish` to `eslint/lib/formatters/<some-other-folder>/stylish` in a newer version of eslint (I think v6). And now this older eslint-loader version is failing to find the updated path in eslint.

So either upgrading `eslint-loader` to a newer version that knows this new path (Easy fix 1), or downgrading `eslint` down to when it had that old path (Easy fix 2), should both work.

For the record I think this outdated dependency is coming from webpack, which makes it difficult to debug for the create-react-app folks.

Comment: Installing eslint worked, however I didn't want it at all. Maybe it's coming from Webpack as you say.

Comment: When using create-react-app, Webpack gives you ESLint whether you want it or not. To get rid of ESLint altogether you probably have to eject the project and then dig through the project yourself to get rid of it.
If the project is not create-react-app, delete ESLint from package.json, delete package-lock.json file entirely, delete node_modules folder, and then do an npm install. This should remove ESLint entirely

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you clean your `node_modules`. Delete your package-lock.json. and run the

`npm cache clean --force` to clean the cache.
Now install the `eslint` by running below in the directory:

`npm i --save eslint`

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late to answer, maybe it's gonna help someone who comes to this thread.

for linux user and using npx just type **npx eslint --init** as the [documentation says](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/getting-started)